# Trying to compile pgAgent. Get an error wx/setup.h: No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio, wxwidgets, pgadmin, pgagent

On one of our servers `pgAgent` service does not start with the message `"ERROR: Couldn't register event handle"` (see [DBA Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207067/pgagent-does-not-start-with-message-error-couldnt-register-event-handle)). So I decided to compile the binary from the source, to further investigate the problem.

I installed [Visual Studio Community 2017 Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/). I downloaded [pgagent source code 3.4.0](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgagent-source-code/) and extracted to `F:\pgbuild\pgAgent-3.4.0`. I downloaded the [wxWidgets 2.8](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/releases/download/v2.8.12/wxMSW-2.8.12.zip), unpacked into `F:\pgbuild\wxWidgets` and built with visual studio 2017. I pointed out the these variables

```
wxMSW=F:\pgbuild\wxWidgets
WXWIN=F:\pgbuild\wxWidgets
PGDIR=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6
WIX=C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\
```

Then I tried to compile the pgAgent. Visual studio could recognize the CMake Project of it. When I compile the cmake project, I get an error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: '../../../lib/vc_lib/mswd/wx/setup.h': No such file or directory  F:\pgbuild\pgAgent-3.4.0\CMakeLists.txt F:\pgbuild\wxWidgets\include\msvc\wx\setup.h    123
```

There are lots of urls around the problem on the net, but I cannot get a handle on it.

It looks to me that this code needs to be updated:

```
#ifdef wxSUFFIX
    #define wxSETUPH_PATH \
        wxCONCAT6(../../../lib/, wxLIB_SUBDIR, /, wxTOOLKIT_PREFIX, wxSUFFIX, /wx/setup.h)
#else // suffix is empty
    #define wxSETUPH_PATH \
        wxCONCAT5(../../../lib/, wxLIB_SUBDIR, /, wxTOOLKIT_PREFIX, /wx/setup.h)
#endif
```

I built wxWidgets using `wx_vc15.sln` in `F:\pgbuild\wxWidgets\build\msw`. I was trying to build pgAgent as CMake project, although [the building instructions](https://github.com/theory/pgagent) say that I need to use the GUI version of CMake.

I was following [instructions to build `pgAdmin`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=pgadmin3.git;a=blob_plain;f=INSTALL;hb=HEAD), but now I am wondering whether I need to build pgAdmin (don't mix it up vs. pgAgent) at all.

Any suggestions how?

Update:

I installed [CMake for Windows](https://cmake.org/download/) and created a solution file to `F:/pgbuild/pgAgent-3.4.0/build`. Got some errors lines back:

[image: Cmake screenshot]

Then clicked on `configure`, then on `gnerate`. This created the visual studio project file. Tried to build it, got the error above (`wx/setup.h`: No such file or directory). The exact error is

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: '../../../lib/vc_dll/mswd/wx/setup.h': No such file or directory  pgagent f:\pgbuild\wxwidgets\include\msvc\wx\setup.h    123
```

Comment: did you first generate the solution/makefile or you just compiled pgagent? Also, did you follow some instructions on how to build? If yes - can you post the link? Finally - how did you build wxWidgets - using command line or through the IDE? Which configuration did you build?

Comment: @igor: nice comments. Updated the task description, and trying to investigate the problem further.

Comment: You may want to consider posting your question to the pgsql-hackers mailing list.

Comment: @Arthur, as Vadim and Gunter suggested, most likely there is a mismatch between wxWidgets build and pgAgent build. Please check Vadim reply and follow on the wx' ML. Also, make sure thaqt you are actually working with wx 2.8 and this is the exact wx version you (pgAgent) requires.